# Features left out when QField project packaged

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfieldsync

When I package my project for QField, for some eldritch reason it leaves out all features on a layer.
Said layer contains around 200 point features, I used this project for months now without any such problems, and suddenly it decided to do this. Project also contains half a dozen tables which are packaged without issue all of their records are intact. The only "new" thing I've done is move around a few points to better reflect reality earlier this week, but I noticed no issue until I tried to package the layer with the QFieldSync plugin. I cannot access the project right now, so the amount of info I can give is limited somewhat.

Comment: Are you trying to write over the prior package or are you writing a new one?

Comment: Write a new one, I noticed that there's some problems when I write over an existing one, since then I always create a new clean package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  A layer with 366 point features, when ported to a QField project had 0 features. My solution was to save the layer with a new name, then re-export the project.  I dont know why this works..